# How to Enable/Disable two Elevated Button in Flutter one after another?

Tags: flutter, dart, button, flutter-test, dart-null-safety

I have two elevated buttons I want to disable if I click the A button and disable the B button if I click the B button then need to disable button A.

Comment: Can you please share what you've already tried to implement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do it with just a single bool variable.

```
bool isAactive = true;
```

and code the buttons like

```
    ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: isAactive
                  ? () {
                      setState(() {
                        isAactive = false;
                      });
                    }
                  : null,
              child: Text('A')),
ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: !isAactive
                  ? () {
                      setState(() {
                        isAactive = true;
                      });
                    }
                  : null,
              child: Text('B')),
```